# How to tell if series is in upper chart or lower chart in tooltip (using highstock)?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highstock to plot two panes at once.
My data are several series, each series contains two different metrics, metric A goes to upper and metric B goes to lower. Different colors are different series. I also use crosshair to connect upper/lower charts together.

When using custom HTML tooltip, I set `shared` to `true` so in tooltip I could access `this.points` for all currently visible series, and showing different info in tooltip based on it's metric A or B.

The problem is series visibility could be toggled by clicking on the legend, but in `this.points`, I don't know how to distinguish `point = this.points[i]` is in upper chart or lower chart.

Each `point = this.points[0]` has a `series.chart` property, but I don't know which property could be used to distinguish them. The `series.chart.yAxis` doesn't look like what I want.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: can you post live example?

Comment: So you need to recognise which pane is or check if serie is visible or not?

Comment: I want to recognize for all visible series, which pane are them.

Comment: which you might get more help with if you post a working fiddle example of your chart.

Comment: Hi @jibriggs, here comes the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rayjcwu/qxLzLoj4/ . Click on the legend (in the bottom) could toggle visibility of particular series. In tooltip, I want to show in different way based on if current series is from upper pane or lower pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `d.series.yAxis.userOptions.index` to specify the index of the pane the point is on:

```
if(d.series.yAxis.userOptions.index == 0)
  html += '<h4 style="color:red"> Volume(' + d.series.name + '): </h4><h5>' + d.point.y + '</h5><br />';
else if(d.series.yAxis.userOptions.index == 1)
  html += '<h4 style="color:blue"> OHLC(' + d.series.name + '): </h4><h5>' + d.point.y + '</h5><br />';
```

You can also use other properties in `d.series.yAxis` to specify the difference between the panes: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qxLzLoj4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your demo! Unfortunately in my application, numbers of series in upper pane and lower pane are the same. So it would be great if there is a property could distinguish this directly.